# Get the value of Component's key React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component

```
export class SearchInput extends React.Component {}
```

Which renders me select with some options

```
render() {
    const options = this.state.data.map(d => <Option key={d.value}>{d.text}</Option>);
    return (
      <Select
        showSearch
        value={this.props.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        style={this.props.style}
        defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
        showArrow={false}
        filterOption={false}
        onSearch={this.handleSearch}
        onChange={this.props.onChangeValue}
        notFoundContent={null}
      >
        {options}
      </Select>
    );
  }
```

SearchInput is imported into

```
class CityForm extends React.Component {}
```

where it basically performes as part of the Form. When In my CityForm I select a City from SearchInput I get a value, which can be submitted for a search. The Problem is, that the value is the name of the city, like Hamburg, Berlin or London. In my POST request I need this:

```
const options = this.state.data.map(d => <Option key={d.value}>
```

In order I get my URL built properlybasically like this:

```
filter?[city_id_eq]=02000000&commit=Search
```

What and how do I pass `Option key={d.value}` into my fetch?

```
fetch(`filter?q[city_id_eq]=${???}`, {
  method: 'POST'
})
.then(response => response.json())
```

Comment: If you want to get the value from the key you've setted, you should pass another props directly and take it from the child component, you can't get the value of the key i guess, or if you can it's a bad practice. Im not sure i understood your question, but i hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an option would have a value too - does this work?

```
const options = this.state.data.map(d => <Option key={d.value} value={d.value}>{d.text}</Option>)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am super new to React. So I added this, but how do I check? cause this 
`fetch(`filter?q[ags8_id_eq]=${value}`)`
returns an error of 
`filter?q[ags8_id_eq]=[object%20Object]`

Comment: What does your onChangeValue handler look like?

Comment: It worked somehow 'automatically' throught some magic, when I just added the value to the options and then smth. like this.state.value in my fetch. Thanks!